# S3 print generic only calls S4 print method if print called explicitly

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I am trying to make a print method for an R S4 object so that the print method is called when you type the name of the object on the console. I am able to construct it so that it calls the correct method when I explicitly call print(), but not when I just type the object to the screen. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
setClass("Person",
     slots = list(name = "character", age = "numeric"))

alice <- new("Person", name = "Alice", age = 40)
print.Person <- function(x,...) print("This is a person object")
setMethod("print","Person",print.Person)

# Behavior that I want
print(alice)
[1] "This is a person object"

# Not the behavior that I want
alice
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Alice"

Slot "age":
[1] 40
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not a great expert on S4 but I don't think you should mix generics, which are S3, with S4. As pointed out in the [show](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/show.html) documentation you can define that method for your purpose,

```
setClass("Person", slots = list(name = "character", age = "numeric"))

alice <- new("Person", name = "Alice", age = 40)

setMethod("show", "Person",
          function(object) print(paste("This is a person object named", 
                                       object@name))
         )

alice
# [1] "This is a person object named Alice"
print(alice)
# [1] "This is a person object named Alice"
```

which is the behavior you are looking for.